# How would I get the name of a blank sheet in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a Google Apps Script that applies a filter function to each sheet in my spreadsheet except for certain sheets. I'd like it to ignore particular named sheets, as well as a "blankSheet" variable. I'd like "blankSheet" to consist of any sheets that have no data in a particular range of cells (A2:H).

I tried the following, but the resulting filter function in my spreadsheet still includes an empty sheet. Thanks for the help!

```
function myFunction() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getDataRange().isBlank()).map(s => s.getName()).join(',');

//set variables
const masterSheet = "master";
const masterSheetFormulaCell = "A2";
const ignoreSheets = ["notifications","main",shts];
const dataRange = "A2:I";
const checkRangeA = "A2:A";
const checkRangeB = "B2:B";
const checkRangeC = "C2:C";
const checkRangeD = "D2:D";
const checkRangeE = "E2:E";
const checkRangeF = "F2:F";
const checkRangeG = "G2:G";
const checkRangeH = "H2:H";
const checkRangeI = "I2:I";
//end set variables

ignoreSheets.push(masterSheet);

const allSheets = ss.getSheets();

const filteredListOfSheets = allSheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1);

let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange},"${s.getSheetName()}" &LEFT(ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeA}),0),ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeA})},'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeB}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeC}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeD}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeE}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeF}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeG}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeH}&'${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRangeI}<>"")`);

let formulaText = "=SORT({" + formulaArray.join(";") + "},10,True,11,True)";


ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaText);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation might be useful for finding blank sheets:

```
function blankSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getDataRange().isBlank()).map(s => s.getName()).join(',');
  Logger.log(shts);
  return shts;//returns an array of blank sheet names
}
```

[isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank())

You said you wanted to assign the array of blanks sheet names to a single const so how about this:

```
const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getRange(2,1,100,9).isBlank()).map(s => s.getName()).join(',');
```

The filter function returns only the blanks sheets and the map section returns only the blank sheet names and the join section return all of the names separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a JS noob, so how do I pass the array of blank sheet names to my ignoreSheets const? Can I add your function into my function? Also, does your function check if the entire sheet is blank? I need it to check just if range A2:H is blank.

Comment: I would just break it apart and integrate it into your code.  Since you know JS it's a simple chain.  The only thing that might be new to you is the isBlank() and I left you a reference.  You probably know the map method and the filter.  To be totally honest I didn't even look at your code because I've done this sort of this a lot in the past.

Comment: BTW undeterminate ranges like `"I2:I"` can cause problems in script because the getRange() of that often returns a lot of nulls at the end which require filtering.  I tend to stick with `getRange(2,9,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();`  or you can add the last row to and A1 notation as a string.  Feel free to ask more if I didn't explain it well enough.  I tend to be a bit terse.  I know because I've incurred the wrath and the answer police a lot lately.

Comment: You're not terse at all, but when I say I'm a JS noob I mean that I've been working with it only for the purpose of this script, this week (so, brand new). Most of this function came from copy/pasting tutorials and videos. How would I break your function apart and integrate it into mine?

Comment: I added a comment and an additional statement to my answer.

Comment: Sorry still not getting it. I tried just adding the const statement and then adding `shts` to `const ignoreSheets = ["Notifications","main",shts];`, and when I run my function I get: "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'shts' before initialization"

Comment: I'm not trying access `shts` before it's initialized.  I guess  that's in your code not mine.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that and everything runs right, but the output in Google sheets still includes a sheet with blank rows (in range A2:I), and as a result I get "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." I've edited my original function above to show what I'm trying.

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong. I updated your last statement by changing `getDataRange` to `getRange` and then specified a range. That output then needed to be concatenated to my array of sheets in ignoreSheets. Ultimately, I added the following:                                                                                             `const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getRange(2,1,100,9).isBlank()).map(s => s.getName());`
`const ignoreSheets = ["Notifications","main"];`                                                    `const ignoreSheets2 = ignoreSheets.concat(shts);`